# WWW::Mechanize VS Curl

Tags: php, perl, performance, curl, www-mechanize

Background: I need to get updated data for all of my users.
            The data resides on a secure site so the script needs to login (using cookies)
            Traverses some inner URLs and then fetch the required data.

Tools: WWW::Mechanize or Curl

What is the best tool for my needs?
Performance is a big issue I need to get the updated data as fast as possible due to the reason that I need to get updated data to lots of users.

Is it possible to fire up multiple requests using the WWW::Mechanize library?

#### Update:

I got it running using Curl.
But I was thinking that I could speed
it up using Mechanize.
Which library performs better 
regarding HTTP req?
Are there any statistics?
Right now i am using Curl with the
multi interface.

Answer (score 3):

WWW::Mechanize is a perl module. Therefore you can use all power of the language with it, e.g. [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) multiple processes.